# dojo Select box, triggering events on select

Tags: javascript, dojo

Hi I am using a dojo select, I have a text box where a certain ID is entered and then based on what is chosen on the select box an action is performed. Now the problem is, suppose over two different requests the action remains the same and the id changes I cant trigger the function with the onChange event. How do i handle this? Even if the user opens the select box and chooses the same item as last time I want the function i've written to be called.

Comment: I suggest that you rethink your UI.  The way that your UI works (from your description) is not very user-friendly nor intuitive.  Your users are going to be frustrated (for example, nobody will know it is necessary to choose the **same** item again if they change the ID).  You should, for example, provide a "GO" button to trigger the action.  That button will be disabled unless the user enters a valid ID and picks a valid item from the listbox.

Comment: please see my comment on the answer below :) I added a go button to make things easy and simple!

Answer (score 0):

onchange fires when any option is changed of the combo box.In your case you are not changing the options so obviously that event will not fired.

You can try `onclick` instead.

Write the same code in `onclick` for the select element (however with some intelligent logic since onclick will keep on firing even before you are able to select any option which may not expected in your case..!).

Comment: yeah i figured i could use a flag and then work with onClick, well just decided to put a nice go button there :P